# How to use Google APIs to reduce in memory usage and to use Advance Google features?

Tags: django, google-api, google-drive-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

- I want to build a system that would allow users to POST videos to their YouTube channel after they are logged in with the google account to my website. The video will be published on the website.
- After that, I also need that the users could comment on the videos that showed on my website, and on YouTube.
- After that, I need that the user's profile pictures will be uploaded to their own Google Drive.

### Tasks:

1. Upload Videos to the website with Youtube **(Youtube Video API).**
2. Comment on videos on the website **(Youtube Comments API).**
3. Upload profile picture to Google Drive **(Google Drive API).**

I don't know where to start, and how to do that any user "Hosts" itself, for example, he can add videos, comments, and host his profile picture.

Using **Django** with **Python3**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! I hope you have a great time here. I have to warn you, however, that the question you are asking is off the site's guidelines. You should limit the scope of your question to one single problem that are you are facing. I suggest you read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I recommend you to tackle one of the tasks first (such as the Google Drive one). You can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) comprehensive quickstart provided by Google itself, which will allow you to write a script that lists the files on your Google Drive instance. Afterwards, you may try to upload files (your profile pictures) to it, following [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) piece of documentation which also includes Python examples.

Further to that, I also recommend that you check out the following links:

- [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) explanation about how OAuth2 works, and more specifically with Google APIs.
- [Documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/README.md) on how to use the Google API Client library for Python.
- [Django social auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django), a plugin for Django that allows your users to log into your platform using their Google credentials.

I hope this is useful to you and that you manage to build a great application.